# Force azure fabric to update services with updated version numbers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

Basically I am looking for a way to deploy azure fabrics where services are updated based on nothing but the version number.

I am working on deploying a service fabric application via azure devops. I have written a script that does a diff and updates the version numbers on ApplicationManifest.xml and ServiceManifest.xml. This script has been tested and it updates the versions correctly for the services that have been changed.

Now, when I try to deploy, I get the following error message:

> ##[error]The content in CodePackage Name:Code and Version:1.0.111 in Service Manifest 'MyMicroServicePkg' has changed, but the version
> number is the same.

This error message keeps showing for one service after another until I have updated the version on every single package. Basically it is forcing me to update every single package.

Here is the publish profile I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/05/fabrictools">
    <ClusterConnectionParameters .... />
    <ApplicationParameterFile Path="..\ApplicationParameters\PublishProfName.xml" />
    <CopyPackageParameters CompressPackage="true" />
    <UpgradeDeployment Mode="Monitored" Enabled="true">
        <Parameters FailureAction="Rollback" Force="True" />
    </UpgradeDeployment>
</PublishProfile>
```

Here is the devops task on yaml:

```
- task: ServiceFabricDeploy@1
  inputs:
    publishProfilePath: $(publishProfilePath)
    applicationPackagePath: $(applicationPackagePath)
    serviceConnectionName: ${{ parameters.connection }}
    overrideApplicationParameter: true
    
    upgradeMode: Monitored
    FailureAction: Rollback
    # 30 mins timeout
    UpgradeTimeoutSec: 3600
```

I have looked up this issue online. Generally people talk about how to make sure all services with code changes have versions updated. In my case, I am positive the versions are updated for the changed services.

How do I configure the deployment such that it **does not** do any code comparison and updates only the services that have an updated version?

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the answer here, based on my experience, is that Service Fabric only deploys the entire application as a single versioned collection of each of the internal packages, but leaves specifics of service deployment accessible to you for customization. So even if you haven't made changes to a single service within that application, ultimately it's still going to be bundled up in the application deployed to the cluster and you're still going to have to make a decision about whether to deploy the service or not (or use the provided Deplooy-FabricInstaller.ps1 script to handle such deployments).

My suggestion (based off my own pipeline) is that if you really trust that your script is detecting changed versions properly and you really want to avoid upgrades for services you haven't made changes to (presumably to cut down on deployment time) is to shift around your approach and instead don't fight the application deployment and instead optimize service installation.

Build the solution as you normally would, and utilize the ServiceFabricUpdateManifests@2 task to let it replace all the versions of each service automatically.

At this point, I generally diverge from the standard pipeline.

- I've got a script that removes the DefaultServices from ApplicationManifest.xml to remove automatic service deployments
- I run a separate script that checks to see if the application already exists or not (to inform whether it's a fresh deployment or an upgrade)
- Based on it being an install/upgrade I take a different deployment task route and capture information about the existing services in the cluster

Once the application has been fully deployed, I wrote a custom script that's similar to the included Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 script that iterates through each of the services and itself installs, upgrades or removes them based on their state in the new deployment utilizing ServiceTemplates to populate configuration values.

Because I control the whole of the actual service install process then, I can infer based on data I collect and pass through the build pipeline what should and shouldn't actually be deployed independent of application deployment.

You might find the customization process a bit easier going this route compared to the approach you're taking.

Comment: thanks. I have been going through this and discussing with a few teams from azure too. where is Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 found?

Comment: When you create the new SF application from the template in Visual Studio, you'll find it under the <SfProjectName>/scripts/Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1